# Subset Columns based on partial matching of column names in the same data frame

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, string-parsing

I would like to understand how to subset multiple columns from same data frame by matching the first 5 letters of the column names with each other and if they are equal then subset it and store it in a new variable.

Here is a small explanation of my required output. It is described below,

Lets say the data frame is `eatable`

```
fruits_area   fruits_production  vegetable_area   vegetable_production 

12             100                26               324
33             250                40               580
66             510                43               581

eatable <- data.frame(c(12,33,660),c(100,250,510),c(26,40,43),c(324,580,581))
names(eatable) <- c("fruits_area", "fruits_production", "vegetables_area",
          "vegetable_production")
```

I was trying to write a function which will match the strings in a loop and will store the subset columns after matching first 5 letters from the column names.

```
checkExpression <- function(dataset,str){
    dataset[grepl((str),names(dataset),ignore.case = TRUE)]
}

checkExpression(eatable,"your_string")
```

The above function checks the string correctly but I am confused how to do matching among the column names in the dataset.

Edit:- I think regular expressions would work here.

Comment: Try with `substr`

Comment: Using `dplyr`, I believe you just want `select(eatable, starts_with("fruit"))`.

Comment: @aichao I tried that. Your suggestion is good but what I want is automatic checking of column names in the data frame if they match, subset.

Comment: Then you can use `grepl` as you did and use the result from that to `subset` your columns `subset(dataset,select=colnames(dataset)[cols])` where `cols` is output from the `grepl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
v <- unique(substr(names(eatable), 0, 5))
lapply(v, function(x) eatable[grepl(x, names(eatable))])
```

Or using `map()` + `select_()`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(v, ~select_(eatable, ~matches(.)))
```

Which gives:

```
#[[1]]
#  fruits_area fruits_production
#1          12               100
#2          33               250
#3         660               510
#
#[[2]]
#  vegetables_area vegetable_production
#1              26                  324
#2              40                  580
#3              43                  581
```

---

Should you want to make it into a function:

```
checkExpression <- function(df, l = 5) {
  v <- unique(substr(names(df), 0, l))
  lapply(v, function(x) df[grepl(x, names(df))])
}
```

Then simply use:

```
checkExpression(eatable, 5)
```

Comment: Nice idea! I thought `substr` is vectorized :)

Comment: Indeed. No need for dplyr for just one functtion

Comment: @Sotos Yup. I guess I'll just leave it as an alternative to base R. It might come in handy if part of a more complex pipeline.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Thank you. It is clear now from your answer and aichao 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may address your needs:

```
checkExpression <- function(dataset,str){
  cols <- grepl(paste0("^",str),colnames(dataset),ignore.case = TRUE)
  subset(dataset,select=colnames(dataset)[cols])
}
```

Note the addition of `"^"` to the pattern used in `grepl`.

Using your data:

```
checkExpression(eatable,"fruit")
##  fruits_area fruits_production
##1          12               100
##2          33               250
##3         660               510
checkExpression(eatable,"veget")
##  vegetables_area vegetable_production
##1              26                  324
##2              40                  580
##3              43                  581
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But Steven's answer is more automated.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does exactly what you want but there was a small error:

```
checkExpression <- function(dataset,str){
  dataset[grepl((str),names(dataset),ignore.case = TRUE)]
}
```

Change the name of the object from which your subsetting from `obje` to `dataset`.

```
checkExpression(eatable,"fr")
#  fruits_area fruits_production
#1          12               100
#2          33               250
#3         660               510

checkExpression(eatable,"veg")
#  vegetables_area vegetable_production
#1              26                  324
#2              40                  580
#3              43                  581
```

Comment: Actually I corrected it in my local R script and getting similar output as yours but there was a mistake while typing it while asking the question. However I edited it and correct the same thing in question. Thank you for noticing. But my question starts after getting the similar output as yours. :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.